# Transfer a SQL Server database without data

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to move a database from a server in one data centre to a server in my local data centre.  The pipe between the two is very slow.  Luckily I only need to transfer the schema, not the data.  Is there an easy way in SQL Server to transfer just the schema of a database without the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Management Studio's Object Explorer and select `Tasks > Generate Scripts ...`

[image]

Then step through the wizard, select those objects you need, select whether to script out to a single file or to a file per table / view - whatever you need.

Then transfer the `.sql` script(s) to the target system, launch Management Studio there, run the scripts - done!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [SQL Server Publishing Wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895179.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to generate scripts of your existing database (in SSMS right-click the database, then Tasks, then Generate Scripts ...).  Go through the wizard to generate your script file(s).  Then run the script(s) on the target system.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of third party tools which can do this for you pretty easily, such as [Red Gate's SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [DB Ghost](http://www.dbghost.com/). ApexSQL has a free, community version of [ApexSQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/promo/apexsql-diff_free-version.aspx?gclid=CLe0ifTLjb4CFUQF7AodEBwA1w). Devart has a [dbForge Studio Express for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/) which has schema compare capabilities.

There are also several other questions on Stack Overflow which provide some ideas:

- [Free Tool to compare Sql Server tables [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/193438/2266979)
- [Best tool for auto-generating SQL change scripts for SQL Server [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688/best-tool-for-auto-generating-sql-change-scripts-for-sql-server)
- [Anyone know of any good Database Diff tools? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104203/anyone-know-of-any-good-database-diff-tools)

[Microsoft's Visual Studio can even do schema comparisons now.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193250%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

But you should be able to script the entire database using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) as [Marc S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23432209/2266979) now describes. This option was also proposed by [Chris Brandsma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9443/chris-brandsma) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1162348/2266979) to [Script entire database SQL-Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1162339/2266979).