# Sharing a SQL file without the data

Tags: sql, database, analytics

I am wondering if businesses can send me their sql file without giving me de data of their company, I am only interested in the structure of the data-base (tables, columns etc.). Is their an easy way to get this structure, and in what form could this file be?

Comment: You can retrieve the creation script of the database. It will be a SQL script (*.sql). The "How" will depend on the database engine you use (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, ...).

Comment: And to add to the comment by @OlivierDepriester you could do this by going to SQL Server Management Studio, right-click the database and go to Tasks > Generate scripts. More information can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162339/script-entire-database-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Businesses *can* share their schema with you if they so desire. That's a decision up to each individual organization, their management, and their legal, risk & compliance departments.

That said, I doubt you'll find any major company giving this information freely. It's considered part of the company's intellectual property and there's no incentive/advantage to them to do so.

What form would it take? most likely one or more plain text files containing the DDL scripts (SQL statements) to build out the schema. But as noted above, you almost certainly won't find a company willing to do it.

Comment: Except if @charlesdem work for an IT company an the businesses he is talking about  are  his customer ;)

Comment: sorry, I think I formulated the question wrong. Is there a way to share your tables with corresponding columns from my sql file. If yes, what is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reaction by the way